# lodash/underscore debouce help - function is never called

Tags: geolocation, underscore.js, lodash

Trying to limit the number of times my updateLocation() function is called below. My understanding is that debounce would limit the calls to 1 every 5 seconds, yet the method never gets hit - debounce seems to debounce everything?

```
var id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (location) {
                _.debouce(function () {
                    updateLocation(location);
                }, 5000);
            }, function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
            }, {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 0});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call debounce once and use the returned value as the success handler:

```
var successHandler = _.debouce(updateLocation, 5000);

var id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( successHandler, ....
```

What's happening in your code is that you're creating a debounced function every time the position changes.

Comment: yeah, my pudding brain is just not getting it. Have implemented as you laid out, but still not seeing the updateLocation called. Perhaps its my understanding: i understand debounce to record at least once per x ms?